# Resetting a password for Brocade 3800 when you don't have support channels

Tags: brocade

Not so sure if this question is considered valid, but I'm trying my luck.
I acquired a Brocade Silkworm 3800 FC switch, and it came with password in it.
I do not have access to Password Recovery Firmware.
Will any of you resident experts point me to a right direction?
Thank You

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

The way I did it was with a "fabric recovery" tool.  But this requires you to have a second switch with a known password.  It erases the configuration (and passwords) from the entire fabric. (yes, a rather dangerous tool)

There's also the (nearly undocumented) root and factory accounts.  WARNING: root access drops you to an os shell (vxWorks) from which you can permanently damage the system.  Login as `root` (passwd: `fibranne`), and issue the command `passwddefault` and then `exit`.

(The linux based systems 3250, 3850 are a bit more involved, but amount to booting in single mode and running `/sbin/passwddefault`)

[BTW, the default user is `admin` with password `password`]

Comment: Thank you Rick for the suggestions.
I tried all four default accounts including the admin/password:
factory:password
root:password
root:fibranne
None of them seem to work.
Unfortunately, I have only one switch.
Do you have a copy of it? Will it be legal to share it?
Many thanks.

Comment: It takes a *second functional switch* to clear the configurations. Even if I did dig up that windows program, it would do you ZERO good.

Comment: If it's old enough, the password might be `fiberann`.

Comment: both root:fiberann and admin:fiberann did not work
Can't believe it is such a pain to reset a password with having a hardware. Cisco is so easy!
Is there anything possibly I could do, or am I outta luck?

Comment: Try this: http://community.brocade.com/t5/Fibre-Channel-SAN/password-recovery/ta-p/1515  Looks like they've released a different, less disruptive "reset" than the simple (and very small) program I used.